# Entity Framework : how to change foreign key one field to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an EF question for you: I have these two classes

```
public class Post 
{
    public long Id {get;set}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get;set;}
}

public class Comment 
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

I created a database at first with these columns and EF created foreign key with `Id` column of `Post` class, but then I added `UniqKey` column as my new primary key:

```
public class Post 
{
    public long Id {get;set}
    public string Content {get;set;}

    public string UniqKey {get;set;} //New Field will be my new primary key

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to change my foreign key to use `UniqKey` instead of `Id`.

I want to update database without deleting and losing any data.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I assume that `UniqKey` isn't actually going to be the new *primary* key? If you want `Post` to refer to `UniqKey`: can't be done in EF6. EF-core allows alternate keys.

Comment: old data cannot be migrated automatically, because old FK's are of type long, you'll have to migrate the data manually after adding new PK values (and adding new FK column and deleting old one after fetching the data). This cannot be done in any of the existing initialization strategies, you'll have to configure an update context with the strategy null. If the new property is not actually supposed to be FK, you'll have to do the join manually in each query because FK's reference the PK column.

Answer (score 0):

You should operate on database first (maybe with management studio if you are using SQLserver or with Toad preferred in this case).

First of all make a back-up of the database.

Then add the column UniqKey with allowed null.

Now update the table and add manually the value of UniqKey.

Remove the constraints and key relative to Id.

Remove allowed null to Uniqkey and add the constraint and the key to it.

In your model add the attribute [Key] and [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Don't forget you have to change also foreign key of Comments

Give a look here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983524/how-to-use-string-property-as-primary-key-in-entity-framework) and here [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025177/how-to-rename-primary-key-column-in-code-first-approach-in-asp-net-mvc) also.

If your database has only these two table you can also think to use database first approach, and use the new context created by wizard instead of old one you created with code-first approach